# How Place a Custom Form Fields in a specific location on the User Profile Page?

Tags: plugin-development

I am seeing a lot of how to add to fields to the user's profile page, via the

```
function your_user_profile_fields($user)
{
//.... code here for field
echo '<h3 class="heading">SubRoles : License</h3>';
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'your_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'your_user_profile_fields' );
```

What I would like to know, is there a way to specifically place where these new fields go?

For example, I want my new field to go directly under the "Role" definition.  The data I am placing is a licensing info and directly related to personal information.

Name

Username XXXX
Role    Customer

**License: XXXXXX** <====== new field here

First Name XXXX
Last Name XXXX

Comment: if the user is an admin, where do you want it display? that field doesn't exist if you are looking at your own.

Comment: I am looking to code it with PHP calls, as in the example. The field does not exist. I can create it, but want to place it in a particular spot, not just show up at the bottom.